# How to make a Java GridBagLayout with six rows and 2 columns

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I'm tired with Java GridBagLayout. I want to create a panel that looks like the one shown in the picture below, but I couldn't get it. I'm unable to position the left panel, and I failed to make panels long. The width does not increase when I set gridWidth. I can't use any GUI builders for that. I want to get a layout like the picture below.

[image]

**This is the unsuccessful code:**

```
public class gui3 extends Frame{
    Panel p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,pmain;
    gui3(){

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500,500);
    setTitle(" Calculator ");


        GridBagLayout gb1=new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
        setLayout(gb1);

        p1=new Panel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        gbc.gridx=5;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        gbc.gridwidth=3;
        //gbc.weightx =0.5;
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(p1,gbc);

        p2=new Panel();
        p2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=1;
        gbc.gridwidth=2;
       // gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(p2,gbc);

        p3=new Panel();
        p3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=2;
        gbc.gridwidth=2;
      //  gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(p3,gbc);

        p4=new Panel();
        p4.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=3;
        gbc.gridwidth=2;
      //  gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(p4,gbc);

        p5=new Panel();
        p5.setBackground(Color.RED);
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=4;
        gbc.gridwidth=2;
     //   gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(p5,gbc);

        p6=new Panel();
        p6.setBackground(Color.pink);
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=5;
        gbc.gridwidth=2;
       // gbc.weightx = 1;
       // gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(p6,gbc);

        p7=new Panel();
        p7.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        gbc.gridx=6;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        gbc.gridheight=6;
     //   gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(p7,gbc);


    }

}
```

Comment: GBC are column based, then to create an matrix with 6/7 columns and 6rows

Comment: everything depends if/how it will be resizable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean something like...

[image: Layout]

So basically, you can use `GridBagConstraints#gridheight` (or `gridwidth`) to set the number of grid cells that a component will span across

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout();
    }

    public TestLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.weightx = 1;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                frame.add(createPane(Color.RED), gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
                frame.add(createPane(Color.GREEN), gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
                frame.add(createPane(Color.BLUE), gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
                frame.add(createPane(Color.CYAN), gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
                frame.add(createPane(Color.MAGENTA), gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
                frame.add(createPane(Color.ORANGE), gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
                frame.add(createPane(Color.PINK), gbc);

                gbc.gridx++;
                gbc.weightx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.weighty = 1;
                gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
                frame.add(createPane(Color.YELLOW), gbc);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel createPane(Color color) {
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(){ 

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(50, 50);
            }

        };
        pane.setBackground(color);
        return pane;
    }

}
```

Have a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: of course that's what i need.it's really helpful .but when i resize it vertically suddenly rows get so narrow.can i avoid from that

Comment: That will occur when the available space is smaller the preferred size of the components. About the only way to really avoid it is to place the component in a scroll pane

Comment: This can be easily fixed; see my answer.

Comment: @JanBodnar Yes, well done, you've taken an out of context problem and provided an arbitrary solution, which could adversely affect what the OP is actually trying to do. Overriding the preferred/minimum sizes of components should be last resort.  Adding components to the panels and providing layout constraints would be a more versatile solution.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well, my post might look like a critique, but it was not meant bo be. It is just that these abrupt changes often confuse the beginners when they use GridBagLayout. I just wanted to communicate that it can be fixed in two ways, setting the minimum size to the preferred size or setting the weights correctly. Both are IMHO valid.

Comment: @JanBodnar Sorry, I was "picking" on a single element, I like the use of MigLayout as a alternative to `GridBagLayout`.  The reason I didn't mention overriding `getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` in my own answer was because I didn't have enough context to what the OP was trying to achieve and this might not be the best solution to their particular problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

The abrupt changes in size from the MadProgrammer's solution can be 
easily fixed in two ways:

```
public JPanel createPane(Color color) {
    JPanel pane = new JPanel(){ 

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(50, 50);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return new Dimension(50, 50);
        }            

    };
    pane.setBackground(color);
    return pane;
}
```

We also provide a mimimum size which is equal to the preferred size.
This way the panels are not shrinking but they are cut from the window
when the container is too small to display them.

The optimal solution is probably to set the `weighty` to 1. The panels will
gradually being shrinking.

```
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
```

Finally, I also created a solution with `MigLayout`. If possible, try
to create your layouts with `MigLayout` rather than with `GridBagLayout`.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutPanels extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutPanels() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Panels");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap"));

        add(createPanel(), "w 200, push, grow");
        add(createPanel(), "push, grow");
        add(createPanel(), "push, grow");
        add(createPanel(), "push, grow");
        add(createPanel(), "push, grow");
        add(createPanel(), "push, grow");

        add(createPanel(), "cell 1 0 1 6, growy");


        pack();
    }

   public JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(){ 

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(50, 50);
            }

        };

        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        return pnl;
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutPanels ex = new MigLayoutPanels();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`GridBagLayout` is a powerful manager which can be used to create most layouts.
Many programmers find it difficult to use. `MigLayout` is easier to understand, 
more powerful, and much less verbose.

[image: Panels]